# How to get from the Helsinki-Vantaa airport into Helsinki city centre?

Tags: public-transport, airport-transfer, finland, helsinki, hel

How to get from the Helsinki-Vantaa airport into Helsinki city centre quickly and without paying too much for it?

Bonus question: how about if the flight arrives in the wee hours (say, at 03:00 am)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Daytime, there are two very good options:

- [HSL](http://www.hsl.fi/EN/) **bus 615** is easy and affordable.  The trip to central railway station costs **5€** and takes some 35 mins. The bus runs every 10-20 minutes between 06:30 and 00:30 on weekdays (Sat 07:00-1:00, Sun 06:05-00:30). (From city to airport, first departure is 05:10 and last   22:45.) At the airport it leaves from T1 (platform 2) stopping at T2 (platform 21) too, and in city centre from platform 3 on [*Rautatientori*, next to the central station](http://goo.gl/maps/wZ3kG). The fare covers transfer to other HSL services – buses, trams, metro, [Suomenlinna](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9043/583) ferry – within 80 mins. Check [615 timetable](http://aikataulut.hsl.fi/linjat/en/s615.html) or the [Journey Planner](http://www.reittiopas.fi/en/?from_in=airport%20&to_in=central%20railway%20station) for more info.
- The **[Finnair City Bus](http://www.pohjolanliikenne.fi/fi/index/aikataulut/finnair-city-bus.html#fcb-english)** ([timetable & route map](http://www.finnair.com/go/2015.4-136/documents/PDFs/FCB_aikataulu0914_WEB_spread.pdf)) takes you a bit faster (average time 30 mins according to the company) from airport to central railway station. The fare is **6.30€**, and it runs (mostly) every 20 minutes, between 05:45 and 01:10 daily. (From city to airport between 05:00 and 24:00).
  This bus leaves from T2 (platform 10) and stops at T1 (platform 1); in city centre, it leaves from *[Elielinaukio](https://goo.gl/maps/07cYj)*, platform 30, on the other side of the central railway station. The Finnair bus also provides free WiFi (details provided on the information display on the bus), which can be handy for travelers.

**Late at night** & early in the morning (i.e., when 615 is not running), HSL **bus [620](http://aikataulut.hsl.fi/linjat/en/s620.html)** is your friend. It runs every half hour mostly, with last departure from airport at 03:55 and from city at 03:10 (Fri & Sat nights 03:40). But first departure is at 05:00 (from city 04:10), so **essentially the whole night is covered**, all week! Night fare (charged between 02:00-04:30) is **7€**. The 620 departs from the exact same platforms as 615, and estimated travel time is 40-45 minutes. (The 620 also has departures during daytime; the main difference compared to 615 is slightly longer travel time.)

A **taxi** is always a convenient option, of course, but it's far from cheap (around 35-40€). There are some fixed rate / shared taxi services too that are slightly cheaper (e.g. [Airport Taxi](http://www.airporttaxi.fi/index_airporttaxi_en.html), "from 19.50€").

**Edit**: updated for 2015. Note that slightly different 615 and 620 timetables may apply in the middle of the summer. Check the [**Journey Planner**](http://www.reittiopas.fi/en/?from_in=airport%20&to_in=central%20railway%20station) to make sure, as it always has up-to-date info on the HSL services.

### Rail connection starting 1 July 2015

The new [**Ring Rail Line**](https://www.hsl.fi/en/ringrailline) opens this summer, bringing a rail connection between the airport and central Helsinki. It won’t really be faster than the current buses, but it’s probably easier, more straightforward for the occasional visitor.

As you can see in the schematic map below, **you can take either I train or P train** no matter which way you're going. To optimise travel time (save 5 minutes), choose **I train from Helsinki** and **P train from airport**.  Both trains will run every 10 minutes in the daytime.

Travel times:

- Helsinki city to airport: I train 27 minutes; P train 32 minutes
- Airport to Helsinki city: P train 27 minutes; I train 32 minutes

[image: Ring Rail Line schema]

(NB: at least some bus of the existing bus lines will remain in operation and may be valid options even after the Ring Line opens. I’ll update this with more details later.)

Comment: Agree! Used the Finair bus this summer sometimes after midnight. Can really recommend it.

Comment: I've actually never tried the Finnair shuttle myself, but it probably is a slightly more comfortable choice. Key advantage of 615 (besides being cheaper) is that you can continue your trip in the city with the same ticket.

Comment: Payment options: in HSL buses you can pay with cash (or [Travel Card](http://www.hsl.fi/EN/passengersguide/travelcard/)), but notes bigger than 20€ probably won't be accepted. In the Finnair City Bus (and taxis) you can pay with cash or credit card.

Comment: Coming from the airport or some city stops you can also buy your ticket from a ticket machine, which accept coin, cash, or credit card (Chip+Pin only!).

Comment: Unfortunately, the Finnair City Bus service has ended. It was suspended starting 23 March 2020 because of COVID-19 and decreased customer numbers. [The notice of ending this service can be found in Finnair's page of local transportation options.](https://www.finnair.com/fi-en/smooth-travelling-at-helsinki-airport/transportation-to-and-from-helsinki-airport)