# Visiting Helsinki during 5h wait between flights

Tags: sightseeing, airport-transfer, layovers, helsinki, hel

Is it realistic to do a quick visit to Helsinki, if I have 5h waiting time between flights? If so, what kind of transport should I take and what is the landmark mostly worth seeing?

Comment: Yes, it's realistic. The **['airport to city centre' question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/getting-from-helsinki-airport-to-city-centre)** is already quite well covered on this site. I'd wander in the centre and go see the [Cathedral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helsinki_Cathedral) at least (like [user1187008 suggested](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/9350/583))

Comment: (Btw, when I fly from HEL, I get there ~60 min before flight time. 90-120 min will be plenty. Getting through to the gates is usually very quick.)

Answer (score 9):

From the airport to the city center you can go by:

- taxi (quite expensive)
- [bus](http://www.helsinki-vantaa.fi/to-and-from/bus-and-taxi-service) (takes 35 minutes)

In both cases, having to wait 5 hours you'll have plenty of time for a quick visit of the city center.
From the train station (nice building) the senate square (with the Luteran cathedral and the university), the Esplanade and the market square are all within walking distance. You could even visit the Uspenski cathedral at the beginning of the Katajanokka peninsula.

Here is a [short itinerary](http://goo.gl/maps/qI4dA) that covers the very center of the city.

Comment: A taxi from the airport to the centre of town was about €35 one-way when I did this trip the other day.